# PDO and access.mdb database change timezone using INSERT query

Tags: php, pdo

I've a problem inserting a date/time field inside a database ACCESS .MDB using PDO connection. I'm working on localhost with WAMP SERVER

I'm working in Italy.

Important: I'M NOT USING MySQL

```
<?php

$dateHour = new DateTime('now');

// var_dump($dateHour);
// OUTPUT:  2018-05-22 12:29:02   <-- CORRECT (hour is the same of my Windows Date/Time at bottom-right of the screen (for ITALY))

$sql = "INSERT INTO table ( DateTime, ... ) VALUES ( ?, ... )";
$s = $db->prepare($sql);
$s->execute(array($dateHour));
```

Now if I retrieve the inserted record, i get a DateTime of 2 hours before!

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = ?";
...
...

// var_dump($result['DateTime']);
// OUTPUT
// 2018-05-22 10:29:02  <--- 2 hour before!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specificy the timezone of your DateTime.

```
$dateHour = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome')
```

I haven't tried to post it to a database, but getting the string by using

```
$dateHour->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

will give the expected time